# Footer disappearing with use of Google Maps

Tags: google-maps, footer

Before I put in the code for a google map, the footer was showing up fine, and still shows up fine on other pages. I have tried playing with floats, absolute/fixed/relative positioning, etc and nothing seems to keep the footer from disappearing.

You can see it briefly before it vanishes [here](http://ashleyandnygil.net16.net/locations.php)

This is the code for the relevant areas:

```
<body>

<div id="nav">
<?php include 'includes/menu.php'; ?>
</div>

<div id="map-canvas"/>

<div id="footer">
<?php include 'includes/footer.php'; ?>
</div> <!--end footer div-->

</body>
```

And the CSS I've used for these areas:

```
#map-canvas { height: 500px; 
            font-family:magic;
            margin-top: -370px;
            float:right;
            width:550px;
            margin-bottom:0px;}
#footer {
        font-family:magic;
        font-size:20px;
        float:left;
        margin-left:150px;
        text-align:center;
        margin-top:25px;
        }
```

Comment: I don't know it this will help with your problem but you have to close `<div>` element for map with `</div>` and not like now.

Comment: Well then. Now I feel like an idiot. Making it a proper closed div tag worked. The only reason it wasn't closed before is because Google's example code for installing the map API had it that way, and I copy and pasted. Think I will email them about it.